# What are all the empirical observations made by Kaṇāda in his Vaiśeṣika Sūtras?

Tags: philosophy, science, pramana, vaisheshika-sutra, kanada

Kaṇāda, the natural scientist and philosopher, appears to have studied nature, made some direct observations and recorded them in his Vaiśeṣika Sūtras.

Wikipedia lists a few but I want to know all of them with references from his sūtras.

Also, did he consider these discoveries of his as resulting from pratyakṣa (perception) or anumāna (inference) or a mixture of both?